# Error en intentacion: expected an indented block

Tags: python

for text, author in history:
            logging.info("text: %s", text)
            logging.info("author: %s", author)

```
        if author == 'bot':
            #print type(text)
            #print type(tree['say'])
            if 'say' in tree and text == tree['say'] and 'answers' in tree:
            #if text == tree['say']:
            #    tree = tree['answers']
        elif author == 'user':
            key = get_key_if_valid(text, tree)
            if key is not None:
                tree = tree[key]
                if 'say' in tree:
                    response_text = tree['say']
                if 'answers' in tree:
                    possible_answers = tree['answers'].keys()
                    possible_answers.sort()
                else:
                    possible_answers = None
```

**aparece el siguiente error**

IndentationError: expected an indented block

```
 elif author == 'user':
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando declaras un bloque (los que terminan en dos puntos) tiene que tener contenido y tiene que ir con sangría (o tabulado o con 4 espacios, tú parece que estás usando espacios).

Todo tiene que ir bien alineado, el primer if tiene que estar al mismo nivel que el elif. En tu código está interpretando que el elif va con el if que está dentro del `if author == 'bot'` y que no tiene la sangría adecuada.

Lo que está pasando es que tienes comentadas las dos lineas que están antes del elif y por eso te da el error de identación. Para que no te de error quita los comentarios de dentro de `if 'say' in tree and text == tree['say'] and 'answers' in tree:` o añade un print o algo para que ese if tenga algo dentro.

Comment: se puede poner un pass es lo mismo pero no hay una linea vacia por el print() igual buena respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo "Boomer" tu

```
if 'say' in tree and text == tree['say'] and 'answers' in tree:
```

no tiene nada (los comentarios son invisibles para python) y por eso da ese error, te recomiendo que pongas "pass" en el if
para que se ejecute codigo pero no haga nada

```
if 'say' in tree and text == tree['say'] and 'answers' in tree:
    pass
```